# Running a bash script gives various basic command not found error

Tags: bash, shell

I am new in bash scripting. I am trying to execute a bash script from my windows 11 system running in power shell terminal. I am in the same path where my bash file is present and I didnot add the folder path in env PATH.

The command I am using to execute the file -

`bash test.sh`

This is the error I am getting -

```
test.sh: line 1: FROM: command not found
test.sh: line 3: RUN: command not found
test.sh: line 6: RUN: command not found
test.sh: line 9: RUN: command not found
test.sh: line 12: ENV: command not found
```

Please suggest.

This is the bash script I am trying to execute -

```
FROM centos:centos7
# Get any CentOS updates then clear the Docker cache
RUN yum -y update && yum clean all

# Install MarkLogic dependencies
RUN yum -y install glibc.i686 gdb.x86_64 redhat-lsb.x86_64 && yum clean all

# Install the initscripts package so MarkLogic starts ok
RUN yum -y install initscripts && yum clean all

# Set the Path
ENV PATH /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/opt/MarkLogic/mlcmd/bin

# Copy the MarkLogic installer to a temp directory in the Docker image being built
#COPY MarkLogic-RHEL7-8.0-5.5.x86_64.rpm /tmp/MarkLogic.rpm
COPY MarkLogic-10.0-9.4.x86_64.rpm /tmp/MarkLogic.rpm

# Install MarkLogic then delete the .RPM file if the install succeeded
RUN yum -y install /tmp/MarkLogic.rpm && rm /tmp/MarkLogic.rpm

# Expose MarkLogic Server ports
# Also expose any ports your own MarkLogic App Servers use such as
# HTTP, REST and XDBC App Servers for your applications
EXPOSE 7997 7998 7999 8000 8001 8002

# Start MarkLogic from init.d script.
# Define default command (which avoids immediate shutdown)
CMD /etc/init.d/MarkLogic start && tail -f /dev/null
```

Comment: That is a Dockefile and needs an docker client to interpret it. Bash doesn't. recognize them

Answer (score 0):

As said by @Inian, the file is a Dockerfile but not a shell script.

You would run:

```
docker build .
```

to build a docker image from the Dockerfile.